# In batch, how would i go about undoing something?

Tags: batch-file, syntax, colors

Im playing around with batch, and im trying to make a little fun thingy. i have a couple problems:

when in either :backcol or :textcol when i change the color of the text or background do a different color, and then answer n/N to :keepbc or :keeptc, how can i make the color return to what it was before i changed the color, and returning to the respective :backcol/:textcol? for example:

**background**
changing the background from black to blue via :backcol -> :keepbc; but then going to change it to a different color like red, but instead of saying y/Y in :keepbc, when i say n/N it changes the background color back to blue, and returns the :backcol.

**text**
changing the text from  green(default) to blue via :textcol -> :keeptc; but then going to change it to a different color like red, but instead of saying y/Y in :keeptc, when i say n/N it changes the text color back to blue, and returns the :textcol.

another problem is if i change the background color to blue, then change the text color, how do i get it to not change the background color back to black? when changing colors of either just the background, or just the text do i need to have the two characters? (02, 4F; like that)

any ideas? thanks! and since im new if theres anything else you see wrong, please help me out! :D

and ignore :premade! not done yet!

```
:start
@echo off
color 02

:main
@echo off
if color==01 color 01
if color==03 color 03
if color==04 color 04
if color==02 color 02
title Tool Help
echo What would you like to do?
echo 1.Hide/Show
echo 2.Settings
echo 3.Exit
set /p ans=
if %ans%==1 GOTO folderhider
if %ans%==2 GOTO settings
if %ans%==3 EXIT /b

:settings
echo Please select and option.
echo 1.Colors
echo 2.Return to main
set /p opt=
if %opt%==1 GOTO coloro
if %opt%==2 GOTO main

:coloro
@echo off
echo 1.Background
echo 2.Text
echo 3.Nice pre-made schemes
set opt=
set /p opt=
if %opt%==1 GOTO backcol
if %opt%==2 GOTO textcol
if %opt%==3 GOTO premade

:backcol
echo 1.Green
echo 2.Blue
echo 3.Aqua
echo 4.Red
echo 5.Cancel
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%==1 color 20
if %input%==2 color 10
if %input%==3 color 30
if %input%==4 color 40
if %input%==5 GOTO settings
GOTO keepbc


:premade


:textcol
echo Select a color.
echo 1.Green
echo 2.Blue
echo 3.Aqua
echo 4.Red
echo 5.Cancel
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%==1 color 02
if %input%==2 color 01
if %input%==3 color 03
if %input%==4 color 04
if %input%==5 GOTO settings
GOTO keeptc

:keeptc
echo Would you like to keep this setting? (Y/N)
set ans=
set /p ans=
if %ans%==y GOTO settings
if %ans%==Y GOTO settings
if %ans%==n GOTO textcol
if %ans%==N GOTO textcol
GOTO textcol

:keepbc
echo Would you like to keep this setting? (Y/N)
set ans=
set /p ans=
if %ans%==y GOTO settings
if %ans%==Y GOTO settings
if %ans%==n 
if %ans%==N color 02
GOTO backcol

:folderhider
@echo off
echo 1.Show
echo 2.Hide
echo 3.Return
set /p hj=
if %hj%==1 GOTO sh
if %hj%==2 GOTO hi
if %hj%==3 GOTO main
GOTO folderhider

:hi
set/p folderr=Please input the folder you want to hide. If none, type none. 
if "%folderr%"==%folderr% GOTO confirm
if "%folderr%"=="none" GOTO folderhider


:confirm
echo Are you sure you want to hide the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==y GOTO hider
if %cho%==n GOTO hi
if %cho%==Y GOTO hider
if %cho%==N GOTO hi
:hider
attrib +r +h +s %folderr%
echo Folder\File Hiden: %folderr% >>Folderandfileshiden.txt
GOTO folderhider


:sh
set /p showern=Please input the folder you want to show 
if "%showern%"==%showern% GOTO unlock

:unlock
echo Enter password to unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== Blutackk11 GOTO fail
if %pass%== Blutackk11 GOTO shower

:fail
echo Invalid pasword
GOTO unlock

if "%showern%"=="" GOTO folderhider

:shower
attrib -r -h -s %showern%
GOTO folderhider
```

Answer (score 0):

### Undoing

To undo the colors you would need to make your own function which stored the color used last. This is a sample file which takes in the value of the color you want. To undo to the last color just type in a `/`.

```
@echo off
set oldcolor=
set newcolor=

:loop
set /p "var=: "
if "%var%"=="/" ( call :undo ) else ( call :col %var% )
goto :loop

:col
:: Store the last color used incase you want to undo
set oldcolor=%newcolor%
set newcolor=%1
color %1
goto :eof

:undo
:: Use the oldcolor variable to undo
color %oldcolor%
goto :eof
```

So to implement this into you code:

```
:start
@echo off
color 02

:main
@echo off  
......................
:shower
attrib -r -h -s %showern%
GOTO folderhider

:: Below is added at the end of your code
:col
set oldcolor=%newcolor%
set newcolor=%1
color %1
goto :eof
:undo
color %oldcolor%
goto :eof
```

And replace every color command in your code with

```
call :col [Color to change to]
```

And to undo simply

```
call :undo
```

Comment: I understand that, but if im changing the color in the executable, from something other than black background, white text, to something else, but hit no in :keeptc or :keepbc, is there a way to make it go back to what it was before i changed the color, so like start with blue background -> select green background, but answer n/N to "Would you like to keep this setting?" and then have it return to blue. and i would like the default to be Black back, green text.

Comment: @LiamHawthorne Look at my edit. It has the method to implement this into your code. However, since I do not know where you want to undo I have left it up to you. Note you will have to replace every color command in the manner I have shown to you.